# what is the meaning of eigenvalue of Dirichlet laplacian in the real life (physics...)

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, applications, laplacian

I am asking a question that I have already asked, but which did not have any success for the answers
let $\lambda_{1}(\Omega),\lambda{2}(\Omega),\lambda_{3}(\Omega)...$ the eigenvlues of the laplacian Operator with Dirichlet condition on the boundary on $\Omega $

the classical spectrale optimisation problem is :
$$ min\{\lambda_{k}(\Omega),\; \Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N open ,\; |\Omega| = c\;\},$$
where  $|.|$denoted the  Lebesgue measure , $c>0$, $k \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and  $\lambda_{k}$ is the $k-$eme eigenvalue of Dirichlet-lapalacian on $\Omega$.

I would like to know what is the application of this Problem (For the laplacian or another Operator) in the physics or the natural sciences..

thank you for your answers

Comment: In that case you can set a bounty on the existing question (if you have enough rep). Posting a question twice is likely not helpful.

Comment: @user202729 yes you are right, but I see this in a probabilistic way

the probability that the person with the answer will look at the question